# Is there any way to set a breakpoint in a colab program and then inspect variable values?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there any way to set a breakpoint in a colab program and then inspect variable values? If not, what's the best way to debug a program while using colab--other than print statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a really good way to do this in Google Colab. *After* you have hit an error, you can create a new code block and run

```
%debug
```

An interactive shell is opened for you at the point of the error with the state still intact and you can examine what the values are.

[Here is some documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.06-Errors-and-Debugging.ipynb#scrollTo=nZkPLuDcxRSd), it's from the [Python Data Science Handbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/) by Jake VanderPlas.

You can also run

```
%pdb on
```

for this to happen automatically on every error

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks.

Comment: How to debug without hitting an error?

Answer (score 1):

When breakpoints are needed and no exception is thrown I use this method (rather hacky tbh). You get the warning but it seems fine to ignore it.

```
import pdb
```

Then insert a set trace call wherever you need the debugger to pause:

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

You'll get an interactive field to issue regular **pdb** commands like **p**(rint), **c**(ontinue) or **l**(ist).

[image: Colab execution paused with pdb active]